# What's the difference between "get to school" and "come to school"?

Tags: meaning

When I want to say "I arrived at school at 8am," the most natural way to say it is *I got to school at 8am*, right?

Why can't I say *I came to school at 8am*?  I feel it's odd to use *came* in this case, but I don't know why.  Could someone explain it please?

Comment: To my ears 'get to school' is specifically about the time of arrival whereas 'come to school is more about the choice to be at school instead of not at school

Comment: _Come_ is a deictic word and refers to the relation between the time of the event and the relation between the speaker, the addressee, and the target location. See Fillmore's [Deixis Lectures](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html) for _come_. _Get_, on the other hand, is simply the inchoative of _be_, meaning 'come to be (located at)' in the context of a locative complement like _school_, and thus specifically refers to the time of arrival.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between "What time do you come to class every day?" and "What time do you go to class every day?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/267812/difference-between-what-time-do-you-come-to-class-every-day-and-what-time-do)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on where you are when you say the sentence.

The following make sense to say if you're not at school, because it's not implied that "school" is "here":

> I got to school at 8am.
>
> I arrived at school at 8am.

The following makes sense to say if you are at school. "Came to school" implies that "school" is "here":

> I came to school at 8am.

Explicitly using "here" makes the following make sense too, even when you're at school:

> I got here at 8am.
>
> I arrived here at 8am.